# Update minor versions of dependencies stored in properties

Tags: maven, maven-versions-plugin

I'm trying to use maven to update to latest minor versions using maven-versions-plugin. The goal `use-latest-versions` has a flag `allowMajorUpdates`. But this will set the versions directly in the dependency.

```
mvn versions:use-latest-versions -DallowMajorUpdates=false
```

Where I'm located they store version numbers in the properties section of the pom.xml. And they want to keep it that way.

```
<properties>
    <!-- This should be updated to 1.3, even if 2.0 exists -->
    <an-app-version>1.2</an-app-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>an-app</artifactId>
        <version>${an-app-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The `update-properties` goal updates the properties like I want, but I don't want to allow major updates.

```
mvn versions:update-properties
```

I'm using maven 3.3.9. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of advantage has the usage of a property in such a setup? Why not writing the version directly into the dependency?

Comment: @khmarbaise I think the argument is that it gives them an overview quickly of the versions in use. Ufortunately i'm not in the position to change their ways.

Comment: The overview can be seen via Eclipse or other IDE's so you don't need to have the properties as that...but of course the versions-maven-plugin should support that...

Comment: @khmarbaise The main advantage is to allow overriding of a version in child projects